# how to used custom definded colors instead of pre defined ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I want to use custom defind colors in my project instead of using the random colors as some of them are not visible on my background. My background is not white so  how can I achieve this.

I want to create a dropdown from which I can select colors and draw layer or can custom define colors in randomcolors function.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var isDown = false;
var startY;

var layers = [];
var currentColor = "black";

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    currentColor = randomColor();
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = false;
    layers.push({
        y1: startY,
        y2: mouseY,
        color: currentColor
    });
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = false;
    layers.push({
        y1: startY,
        y2: mouseY,
        color: currentColor
    });
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    drawAll();
    hLine(startY, currentColor);
    hLine(mouseY, currentColor);
}

function drawAll() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layer = layers[i];
        hLine(layer.y1, layer.color);
        hLine(layer.y2, layer.color);
    }
}

function hLine(y, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function randomColor() {
    return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

The working fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/1/

Comment: Change `currentColor = randomColor();` to the color you want to use

Comment: `currentColor = "red";`

Comment: there should be many colors instaed of only one. as I am able to many layers and each should be of different colors

Comment: Well, then you need to develop a system to choose the color before you start drawing lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an input for `select`, and utilize that value via `jQuery`
.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/3/

```
<select id="pickCol">
  <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
  <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
  <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
</select>
```

**And JS:**

```
currentColor = $("#pickCol").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a selection with color as option like this:

```
<select id="cmbColor">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Then, in your random color function, return this instead (and change the name of the function as well)

```
function randomColor() {
    return document.getElementById("cmbColor").value;
}
```

The line that will be drawn will be of the color of the select !

EDIT:

With html5, you can even add and input like this:

```
<input id="txtColor" type="color">
```

And it will prompt the user with a color picker form! (work only with html5 though)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/2/)

Comment: Well, 8 min behind ;) Thanks !

Comment: I'm at work right now lol. Guess I should focus on actually developing things huh? Upvoting your post :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. how can I use this <input id="txtColor" type="color">

Comment: If you want to use the type color, place the input in your html, then replace your randomColor function by: `return document.getElementById("txtColor").value;`

Comment: @Shryme Instead of user entering a text color can we add a functionality of picking a color from a bunch of colors and draw with that new color(this will be different from predefined colors in a drop down menu)

Comment: Well the input type="color" do this but only on html5, so if you only see a input text it's because your browser don't support it =( But there are script that let you do that in javascript, first one I found is [JSColor](http://jscolor.com/try.php). It let you create a input where the user can choose a color by clicking on it and all you have to do is change your input to: `<input class="color" value="ffffff">`

Comment: @Shryme I did change my input but how can I change my function random color according to that. jscolor is working in my browser. But I dont know how the user will draw line according to that particular color.

Comment: I want my layers to be drawn with the color selected from the palette.

Comment: Please select an answer that you feel suits your needs and answers the question asked.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Both your and Shryme solution meets my need. I have added the color palette from jscolor and cally the random function with document.getElementByClass but its not working. Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/5/

Comment: You can't use two `returns` in the same `function`. You are not calling the `randomColor function` anywhere as well. And it's `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: You should post a new question because that fiddle is full of things that can makes it go wrong, nowhere in your code you take the color inside the input, you wrote a - instead of } and you never implemented the event except mouseDown that do nothing. Also, you don't call hLine (that's your function that is drawing lines!)

Comment: Sorry @Shryme something went wrong in updating the fiddle. My mousemove is using the hline function . here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/6/

Comment: @user3191909 [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/7/) You were trying to access the color with getElementByClassname and it wasn't working, don't exactly know why, but adding id="txtColor" to the input and getting the color with `document.getElementById('txtColor').value` worked!

Comment: @Shryme But It is not drawing with the selected color. it is drawing with the black color.

Comment: @user3191909 Please post this extended discussion as a new question. The original post has been answered, and this is hard to track for anybody that hasn't been following it (myself and @shryme).

Comment: @NicholasHazel the new question has been asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173504/custom-pick-using-js-color-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to change this line of code `currentColor = randomColor();` It can be found here:

```
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    currentColor = randomColor();  //<---- Right Here//
    isDown = true;
}
```

For example, some thing like: `currentColor = 'red';` will give you this: http://jsfiddle.net/Vnsx6/

Comment: by using this I will have only one color ie RED . I should be able to create different color layers.

Comment: @user3191909 I see, I didn't get that from your post. What defines the colors used? Do you decide or does the user? EDIT Nevermind, it looks like Shryme already posted what you are looking for.

Comment: We can give the user a dropdown menu from which he/she can decide which colors to use.

Comment: @user3191909 Shryme has your answer then