# custom pick using js.color not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I 'm trying to pick a custom color using javascript library js.color but it is not picking up color to draw lines in the code. 
It is selecting the color but not drawing the lines with the same.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var isDown = false;
var startY;

var layers = [];
var currentColor = "black";

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    currentColor = randomColor();
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = false;
    layers.push({
        y1: startY,
        y2: mouseY,
        color: currentColor
    });
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = false;
    layers.push({
        y1: startY,
        y2: mouseY,
        color: currentColor
    });
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    drawAll();
    hLine(startY, currentColor);
    hLine(mouseY, currentColor);
}

function drawAll() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layer = layers[i];
        hLine(layer.y1, layer.color);
        hLine(layer.y2, layer.color);
    }
}

function hLine(y, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function randomColor() {

    return document.getElementById("txtColor").value;

}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

The working fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/UfuDX/7/.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are getting the value from the `select`. Also `randomColor()` just gets the value of the textbox which doesn't change.

Comment: @Jack I am not using select anymore. I want to select the color picked from the colorpicker and draw line according to that. The value of the color picker changes as you select different color from that.

Comment: Using the colorbox works for me. What browser are you using? Any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work in chrome just fine. Firefox however didn't like the color value. Adding the `#` to the beginning seems to work, which makes sense since they are hex values.

Change your `randcomColor()` to the below.

```
function randomColor() {
    return '#'+document.getElementById("txtColor").value;

}
```